# Getting navigation.state outside of a screen in react-navigation v5/v6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-v6

I'm trying to upgrade a react-native v4 app to v5/v6. In v4, `createAppContainer` was used like so:

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

and `AppNavigator` would receive a `Navigation` prop that could be used like:

```
type AppNavigatorProps = {
    navigation: Navigation;
};

class AppNavigator extends Component<AppNavigatorProps> {

    isSplashScreen = (): boolean => {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        return navigation.state.index === RouteIndexes.SplashScreen;
    };
    render(): ReactNode {
        // styling set-up here

        return (
            <>
                <SafeAreaView style={topStyle} />
                <SafeAreaView style={bottomStyle}>
                    <StatusBar backgroundColor={barColor} />
                    <ErrorBoundary
                        navigation={navigation}>
                        <RootContainerStackNavigator navigation={navigation} />
                    </ErrorBoundary>
                </SafeAreaView>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out a way to get that `navigation.state` in this location anymore. I have the `AppNavigator` wrapped in `NavigationContainer` instead of the `createAppContainer` like so:

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <AppNavigator />
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `useNavigation` or `useNavigationState` hook ? You might need to convert your existing class component to functional one in order to use it.

Comment: @Tarik yup I tried that as well following the instructions here for a class component https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation-state/